# Como pegar o próximo ID a ser inserido?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica, fechamento, razões-fechamento

Não percebi o porquê de esta pergunta [Como pegar o próximo ID a ser inserido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45634/como-pegar-o-pr%C3%B3ximo-id-a-ser-inserido) estar a ser negativada e votada para fechar como "não é claro o que você está perguntando". Para mim é bem claro o que ele está perguntado.

O que acham?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

*Só reparei agora que a pergunta é de 01/01.*

Comment: O primeiro voto para o fechamento foi meu, fiz isso porque a pergunta foi 'meio que abandonada' se você olha a primeira versão da pergunta ela é bem parecida com [essa outra](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45676/91) que o OP fez no dia seguinte.

Comment: @rray fizeste muito bem, podia era ter sido como duplicata da outra. De qualquer forma o que está em jogo são os votos posteriores, em que a pergunta já estava aceitável.

Comment: Na segunda pergunta, ele aceitou inverter a ordem das coisas. Na primeira, ele insistia que queria saber o "próximo" ID, e criar a pasta antes do INSERT. Precisei comentar várias vezes até que ele entendesse que a ordem deveria ser outra.

Answer (score 2):

Creio que a pergunta havia sido mal formulada no início. Houve muitas edições até chegar ao conteúdo atual.

Além disso, o AP estava com um entendimento incorreto sobre o incremento de IDs e projetou sua pergunta de uma forma errada, isto é, ele estava pedindo para fazer algo que não deve ser feito.

Portanto, creio que os votos negativos refletem a falta de entendimento sobre o AP sobre o assunto.

Não concordo com os votos negativos, pelo menos não com essa quantidade. Bastaria orientar o AP com comentários ou mesmo uma resposta que mostrasse a ele como atingir o seu real objetivo sem a gambiarra que a pergunta espera.

Comment: As vezes dá-me ideia que as pessoas votam só por ver os outros. Eu vi 2/3 votos negativos assim como a pergunta está agora. A mim parece-me um ótima pergunta, daquelas que pode ser histórica. Ela levou o 2º voto para fechar também como já está.

Comment: Sim concordo. Se ele estava com entendimento incorreto, um comentário bastava para ele reformular a pergunta, depois de saber essa informação.

Comment: @JorgeB. Você não está errado. A maioria do votos contra, e todos para fechar, veio depois que a pergunta já estava, por horas, próxima do formato atual.

Comment: @JorgeB. **Um** comentário certamente não bastou. Eu deixei inúmeros, até que ele deixou de responder.

Comment: "As vezes dá-me ideia que as pessoas votam só por ver os outros." Pelas filas de análise, sem dúvida, muitos fazem isso, infelizmente. @JorgeB.

Comment: @bfavaretto quando eu disse "um comentário bastava", queria dizer que comentar era suficiente para o AP saber no que estava errado. É a minha opinião.